# media queries not working for samsung or ipod

Tags: html, media-queries

Im trying to make my website responsive, however Im having a little problem.
It works fine on my browser. If my browser is full screen then it looks how it should, and if I make the browser smaller then the media queries work perfect.
However if i then load onto a samsung galaxy S3 or ipod touch, it does not. It looks like the regular website, only crammed in smaller to fit the screen. It does fit 100% of the screen, however hot at all like it should.
I have searched through here for an answer. I have tried changing the widths, I have tried changing px to em. I have tried being less specific and just write for portable devices. Still doesnt work.
Can anyone help?
This is my media query..

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width:600px)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Responsive width is too small on phone, but okay on desktop browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195904/responsive-width-is-too-small-on-phone-but-okay-on-desktop-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this between your head tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: That actually worked, however not quite right. Some of the divs are not acting how they should.

Comment: Can you be more specific? If I had to guess, it just requires that you make additional changes to the styles for your mobile media query.

Comment: if some divs are not acting the way they should then it's your css that needs to be corrected. This answer is correct

Comment: just noticed I was using my old version to test. I will update you shortly