# Responsive width is too small on phone, but okay on desktop browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am practicing responsive web design. From what I've learned so far, it revolves around a fluid grid with fluid components, and CSS media queries.

The website looks just like how I want it to look like on a mobile phone when I shrink my browser:

[image: browser]

However, when on my mobile phone, after being put on my web server, it looks completely different:

[image]

I think there is some conflict between width and device-width that is occurring. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

This is how i load my stylesheets:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/stylesheets/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width: 600px), screen and (max-device-width: 600px)" />
```

Comment: Did you remember to add the meta tag such as this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" /> ?

Comment: unbelievable. none of the numerous articles I have read mentioned that. this fixed it immediately. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not responsive without viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

More about viewport meta tag
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag