# Media Query not working for Samsung Galaxy Tab3

Tags: css, media-queries

I have written a media query as below. The media query works fine on iPad (Landscape and Portrait). But when viewing the site on a Samsung Galaxy Tab3 (600 X 1024) portrait view, the site completely breaks down. I am not sure if this has got something to do with the Device-pixel ratio.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [media queries not working for samsung or ipod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620285/media-queries-not-working-for-samsung-or-ipod)

Comment: Have you tried this "@media (max-width: 1024px) { }" or "@media all and (max-width: 1024px) { }"

Comment: @SaurabhLP, Thanks for sharing your opinion. I tried that but didn't work.

Comment: Please try this link also i think it will solve your problem: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/